# Linkedin API - Positions field

Tags: linkedin-api

How come when I use apigee to test LinkedIn API I get my 6 positions but when call the API with the access token from my webapp I only get my 2 current positions ?

```
// apigee
"positions":  {
    "_total": 6,
    "values":  [...]
}

// webapp
"positions":  {
    "_total": 2,
    "values":  [...]
}
```

Is it due to the new access limitation ?

Comment: What are the urls you are using to get the data in  web and apigee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the apigee API console has elevated access to full profile info. This was a problem for me too at first - since LinkedIn links to that console from their developer site. But if, during authentication from the apigee console, you look closely at the authentication window (where you type in your LinkedIn credentials), you will see the stuff you are granting access to. That list includes FULL PROFILE. For an application to have the access, you must be a LinkedIn Partner.